# Trouble with shooting for platformer game

Tags: java, arraylist, game-development, 2d-games

I'm trying to make a basic platformer in java but am running into troubles when trying to make the player shoot. Specifically, I get an OutOfBoundsException when moving and shooting in the same direction. I am using an `ArrayList` of bullets. Here is my code in the main game loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < attack.size(); i++) {
    Attacks p = attack.get(i);
    if (p.isVisible() == true) {
        p.update();
        for (int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++)
            checkCollisionAttacks(p, enemies.get(i));
        for (int k = 0; k < platforms.length; k++) {
            checkCollisionAttacks(p, platforms[i]);
        }
    } else {
        removeAttacksList.add(p);
    }
}
removeAttacks();
```

Here is my `removeAttacks` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i<removeAttacksList.size(); i++) {
    attack.remove(removeAttacksList.get(i));
    System.out.println("removed");
}
removeAttacksList.clear();
```

I had originally removed the bullets in the `checkCollisionAttacks` method, but then thought that this is what could be causing the error as I am effectively modifying the `ArrayList` as the loop is ongoing, so I added all the bullets to be deleted to `removeAttacks` to be removed after the loop ends. However, I still receive this error when moving and shooting in the same direction. Why could this be happening?

Comment: I could not find a `OutOfBoundsException` class. Do you mean `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: @Abra yes thats what i mean